# Database connectivity ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I've googled this question repeatedly, but have not found a great answer anywhere. I'm sure someone familiar with ASP.net could answer this pretty easily. What is the best way to connect to a database through ASP.net? LINQ to SQL? Entity framework? I'm not able to find an overview of the different methods to connect or of the place that these technologies have in ASP.net. An explanation or a pointer to a great link would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This question is to broad. It totally depends on your situation and your needs. Maybe if you describe your situation in more detail, we can help.

Comment: I'm looking for a broad answer. As far as I've been understanding, there are different methods to connect to and manipulate databases using ASP.net. I'm wondering what those methods are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, a question without a clear cut answer as it depends on your application need, flavor of database you need to interact with, standards currently in place at your target deployment environment and application design considerations.

Most often relational database access is accomplished in asp.net through either direct or indirect usage of ado.net.  If you plan on adhering to common, current practice you should look into using an ORM to speed development time, namely either Entity Framework or NHibernate. (Linq to SQL was great for SQL Server but has been eclipsed by EF.). My preference is NH.

Sorry for the somewhat subjective answer, but this is unintentionally a subjective question.

Good luck!

Comment: No, your answer is what I'm getting at. So, Entity Framework, NHibernate, ADO.net. Linq To Sql is outdated. Sound about right?

Comment: Microsoft's recommendation these days will be EF. NH is also popular, and both of those are ORMs that use ADO.net under the covers.  ADO.net (System.Data and related) are the core of relational database access in .net, correct.

Comment: if you want a simple light weight ORM try dapper-dot-net http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ it should be more than suitable to get you started and it's what much of stackoverflow runs with